# Leveling sloped floors

Tags: subfloor, slope

I live in Decatur, Ga., a suburb of Atlanta.  I live in a condo that has sloped floors due to settling issues.  I was told the slope is 4” from the front to the back.  The subfloor is concrete.  The building in which my unit exists has several floor jacks underneath.  Earlier this year a new joist(?) was placed underneath the building with the purpose being to minimize any further issues.  I’ve read and seen the videos of shims and plywood, but am open to any solutions.  If additional information is needed, I’ll do my best to supply it.

Comment: 4 inches is a lot in 12 inches, 4 inches over 12 or 20 feet not that much.  What are you planning that needs a level floor?  Guessing this is the problem.  Most flooring want a flat(no dips or humps) floor not a level floor.  Using the floor to play pool you want it nice and level.

Comment: Crip659 from the front of the unit to the back is approximately fifty feet. If I can get the floors fixed, I might consider selling and moving into a pup tent.

Comment: At 50 feet can you even feel that slope when walking around?  If not I would not even bother with it.  All flooring only cares about flatness not if a floor is levelled.  Does the slope bother your walking or just your head because the has a slope?  It does seem like it is the building that has the problem, not just your floor.  What happens if you level your floor, and then they jack up the building?

Comment: What's the actual question here? Are you trying to level your floor? The whole building? Do you need to install new flooring? Does it just bother you? Are you trying to sell currently and people are backing out because they can feel the slope of the floor? Please [edit] your question to tell us exactly what your question is and at least _some_ of the why.

Comment: there is nothing you can do to stop further building sinking. Soon you might see foundation cracking, the walls cracking and more.

Comment: @Ruskes - there is plenty that can be done to stop further building sinking.  It's expensive, but it sounds like things are being done.  (A separate question is whether _enough_ is being done.  Some people don't want to pay for expensive underpinning and can slow down remedial works.)

Comment: @Ruskes, tell that to the folks who take care of the Leaning Tower of Pisa...